# Enabling sharing of posts in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a rails application wherein I want to have the feature of sharing in social sites like facebook, instagram, twitter and pinterest. However, whenever I search in google, I am getting options just for the social-share-button which is for the buttons. I am using rails-5
Can anyone help me out?
I am new to all this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then what you need? Do you need API kind of stuffs?

Comment: Yes I want to know how can that be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

There are various services available on the Web, but If you want simple sharing feature use [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/). It supports more than 70 social networking websites including `WhatsApp`. They also provide you the stats.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

To have the share features in web page, this ruby gem is more than enough - https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button

But if you want to customise the sharing features, all services providing the REST APIs to post the content to their service. Also, ruby wrapper gems are available to access those APIs.

1. Facebook - https://github.com/arsduo/koala
2. Twitter - https://github.com/sferik/twitter
3. Instagram - https://github.com/facebookarchive/instagram-ruby-gem
4. Pinterest - https://github.com/realadeel/pinterest-api

P.S: Read their API documentation before using that.

Comment: I just want a share feature. But using https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button , whenever I click a social network site, it just moves to the top of the page.

Comment: Did you check any logs printing in the console? Both rails logs and console logs in browser.